# Image Corrupt or Truncated on DIV Background

Tags: php, jquery, css, ajax, image

I have this code where you click a button to upload multiple files. When user have select the images, it will automatically upload the files, then preview show the uploaded files. But this error appeared when preview list appear (sometimes few images loaded successfully).

I'm using Ajax and Form Data to send the images, return an array of successful uploaded image's names, and append preview div when completed. The image upload is working fine, so here's my code on the Ajax success return:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'process.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: form_data,
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    success: function (data) {
        if(data){
            $.each(data, function(index, value) {
                var img = "'../content/"+brand+"/"+category+"/"+value+".png'";
                $('<li id="product-'+value+'" class="product item-flex-2"><div class="list-menu border-bottom"><a href="#" title="Delete Product"><i id="delete-product-'+value+'" class="fa fa-remove pointer color-red-hover"></i></a></div><div id="img-'+value+'" class="img-wrapper" style="background-image:url('+img+')"></div></li>').insertBefore($('#product-new'));
                $('#upload-product').val();
            });
        } else {
            alert('Upload Failed.');
        }
    },
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false
});
```

Here's the code on PHP file that process upload file:

```
$product = array();
$brand = $_POST['brand-owner'];
$category = $_POST['category'];
$res_dir = '../content/'.$brand.'/'.$category.'/';
$count = count($_FILES['upload-product']['name']);
$last_file = count(array_diff(scandir($res_dir), array('..', '.', 'index.html')));
$html_dir = $res_dir.'index.html';
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    $last_file++;
    $tmp_file_name = $_FILES['upload-product']['tmp_name'][$i];
    $new_name = $res_dir.str_pad(($last_file),3,0,STR_PAD_LEFT).'.png';
    $create_png = imgToPng($tmp_file_name);
    if(imagepng($create_png, $new_name)){
        array_push($product,str_pad($last_file,3,0,STR_PAD_LEFT));
    }
}

generateHTML($html_dir, 'product', $brand, $category);

echo json_encode($product);
```

Here's imgToPng function code (if needed):

```
function imgToPng($tmp_file_name) { 
    $create_png = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($tmp_file_name));
    imageAlphaBlending($create_png, true);
    imageSaveAlpha($create_png, true);
    return $create_png;
}
```

I also have preview menu with similar code as above, and the error also appear there. I've tried CTRL + F5 to force refresh but it only works after few attempts. I've searching look around but most is about Firefox's Bug (i'm on 48.0.2) or the error is on img tag. I have another html page that use img tag and show no error, but i need to use div on this page.

Thank you...

Update : It looks like the image is corrupt after converted to png. I tried with original extension and the images load correctly. So either my code is incorrect or something wrong with PHP function.